# Can't remove the X-Priority header while sending mail

Tags: php, email

I'm sending mail and using the wordpress SMTP plugin, however I have a problem that each time I send mail, on the debugging output I see the X-Priority header being sent which makes my MQS to drop with SpamAssassin.

I've set `$phhmailer->SMTPDebug=false;` and setting priority to null but it doesn't change anything.

The part of debug output looks like this:

```
 ["MIMEHeader":protected]=>
  string(443) "Date: Tue, 5 Apr 2016 08:44:48 +0000
Return-Path: 
To: web-z4CIb1@mail-tester.com
From: Example
Subject: WP Mail SMTP: Test mail to web-z4CIb1@mail-tester.com
Message-ID: <2edb8cb56706f6d09a29b49a66cf1ff0@example.com>
X-Priority: 
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of poking around I managed to fix the issue by opening up the phpmailer class file, and commented out the following line:

```
$result .= $this->headerLine('X-Priority', $this->Priority);
```

This removed the X-Priority header completely.

Comment: Good to hear that you solved your problem. Just make sure you remember to edit the same code once you upgrade phpMailer in the future. I would still recommend adding Priority 2 (normal) to your emails instead as it will make the application more robust, IE. not having custom edits in third-party classes.

Comment: Well adding Priority 2(normal) still adds the x-priority header, that is why I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If X-priority is removed from the header the email will be handled as priority 2 (normal). Instead of removing the header item, could you set it to 2?

You should be able to unset the header by using `$mail->Priority = null;`
according to [this closed issue](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/577) over at GitHub.

There can be other things affecting your spam score as well, not only the empty Priority variable.

Comment: I can't - I need to completely remove the X-Priority header.

I was setting $mail->Priority = null; but that was not helping. It set the Priority->NULL property in the object that was being created but the X-Priority header was still there, even though the value was blank.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `$mail->Priority = null;` is the correct solution (or do not set it at all as the default is null). However, in order for it to work you will also need to make sure you have a version of PHPMailer that has been updated with [this patch](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/449).